# Getting the AppData/Roaming folder inside Windows GitHub action

Tags: windows, environment-variables, github-actions

I'm writing a GitHub action that needs to write data to `{User}/AppData/Roaming`. I assume there's an environment variable for this but I don't know what it is or how to access it. Is it `%APPDATA%` or something else?

Comment: Did you try verifying it by printing the value of `%APPDATA%` in a GHA workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Powershell script to get the information and store it in an environment variable. I inserted this as a step in the job:

```
    - name: Get AppData Directory
      run: echo ("APPDATA_DIR=" + $env:APPDATA) >> $env:GITHUB_ENV
```

Note that you have to do an echo because the `set-env` command no longer works. After this code has been run, the variable can be accessed by doing `${{ env.APPDATA_DIR }}`.

Comment: Why don't you directly access it instead of setting it to `GITHUB_ENV` first e.g. in PowerShell (`$ENV:APPDATA`) and in cmd (`%APPDATA%`)? This step is completely redundant as `APPDATA` is already available.

Comment: @Azeem Because I was sending it as an argument to another script and therefore I needed access to it within the GitHub action workspace, rather than inside of Powershell. I already tried your method and it didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean you needed it as a configuration parameter for some other action? If yes, it makes sense. I thought you only needed it in Powershell or Command Prompt.

Comment: @Azeem Yes, that is what I meant. I used Powershell because that was the default terminal I had setup for other steps on the same job.

Comment: Right. You might want to add more context to your question about the requirements i.e. how you're accessing it and why it needed to be set as an env var.